# regex ip address with optional port and localhost

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression to detect an ip address (ipv4) with an optional port,
I would like also to support the host `localhost`. I am not very familiar with regex... how to update it so `localhost` is also valid?

```
/\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)(?::\d{0,4})?\b/
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
/(localhost|\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)(?::\d{0,4})?\b)/
```

test:
https://regex101.com/r/fsY4XL/1/
and [visualization](https://regexper.com/#%2F%28localhost%7C%5Cb%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A25%5B0-5%5D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5Cd%7C%5B01%5D%3F%5Cd%5Cd%3F%29%5C.%29%7B3%7D%28%3F%3A25%5B0-5%5D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5Cd%7C%5B01%5D%3F%5Cd%5Cd%3F%29%28%3F%3A%3A%5Cd%7B0%2C4%7D%29%3F%5Cb%29%2F)